# The call stack size of quick sort

Tags: quicksort, callstack, space-complexity

I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12573403/1065835) and found an implementation of Quicksort [here.](http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Sorting/Quicksort) It's still unclear to me why Quicksort requires O(log n) extra space.

I understand what a call stack is. I applied the implementation stated above to an array of random numbers and saw `n - 1` calls of `quickSort`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        int num = 8;
        int[] array = new int[num];
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            array[i] = random.nextInt(100);
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));

        quickSort(array, 0, array.length - 1);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }

    static int partition(int arr[], int left, int right) {
        int i = left, j = right;
        int tmp;
        int pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];

        while (i <= j) {
            while (arr[i] < pivot)
                i++;
            while (arr[j] > pivot)
                j--;
            if (i <= j) {
                tmp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = tmp;
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }

        return i;
    }

    static void quickSort(int arr[], int left, int right) {
        System.out.println("quickSort. left = " + left + " right = " + right);
        int index = partition(arr, left, right);
        if (left < index - 1)
            quickSort(arr, left, index - 1);
        if (index < right)
            quickSort(arr, index, right);
    }
```

The output I saw:

> [83, 65, 68, 91, 43, 45, 58, 82]
>
> quickSort. left = 0 right = 7
>
> quickSort. left = 0 right = 6
>
> quickSort. left = 0 right = 4
>
> quickSort. left = 0 right = 3
>
> quickSort. left = 0 right = 2
>
> quickSort. left = 0 right = 1
>
> quickSort. left = 5 right = 6
>
> [43, 45, 58, 65, 68, 82, 83, 91]

It makes that 7 (n -1) calls. So why does quickSort require O(log n) space for its call stack if the number of calls depends on `n`, not `log n`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Intuitive explanation for why QuickSort is n log n?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425506/intuitive-explanation-for-why-quicksort-is-n-log-n)

Comment: @DavidW, the answer you mention is about the time complexity. But my question is about the space complexity

Comment: I thought the space complexity of Quicksort was, in fact, O(n)

Comment: And my apologies for misreading the post. You're right - it's not about time complexity. I rescinded the close/dup vote.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand why the stack size of Quicksort is `O(n)` in the worst case.

One part of the array (suppose **left**) to be sorted consists of one element, and the other part (**right**) consists of `n - 1` elements. The size of the left part is always 1, and the size of the right part decrements by 1 every time.

Thus, we initially call Quicksort and then call it `n - 1` times for the right part recursively. So extra space for the call stack is `O(n)`. And since the partitioning procedure takes `O(n)` for every recursive call, the time complexity is `O(n2)`.

As for the average case analysis, now I don't know how to prove `O(n * log n)` for the time complexity and `O(log n)` for extra space. But I know that if I divide the input array into two almost equal parts, I'll call Quicksort `(log n) / 2` times for the left part. And the right part is sorted using tail recursion which doesn't add to the call stack.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

So extra space needed for Quicksort is `O (log n)` in this case. The constant factor `1/2` is left out.

Since the partitioning routine is `n`, the time complexity is `O(n * log n)`.

[image]

---

*Please correct me if my assumptions are wrong. I'm ready to read and accept your answer.*